# AWS site down issue because cpu utilization reach 100%

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance with instance type `m3.medium` and an Amazon RDS database instance.

In my working hours the website goes down because CPU utilization reaches 100%, and at night (not working hours) the CPU utilization is 60%.

So please give me right solution for this site down issue. I am not sure why I am experiencing this problem.

Once I had set a cron job for every minutes, but I was removed it because of slow down issue, but still I have site down issue.

[image: CloudWatch chart]

When i try to use "top" command, i had shows below images for cpu usage, in which httpd command consume more cpu usage, so any suggestion for settings to reduce cpu usage with httpd command
Without website use by any user below two images:
**http://screencast.com/t/1jV98WqhCLvV**
**http://screencast.com/t/PbXF5EYI**
After website access simultaneously 5 users
**http://screencast.com/t/QZgZsiNgdCUl**

Comment: Too little details. Since this RDS instance is serving website,  you must check the website log file to find out which program trigger high RDS CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are CPU Utilization is reaching 100% you have two options.

1. Increase your EC2 Instance Type to large.
2. Use AutoScaling to launch one more EC2 Instance of same Instance Type.

Looks like you need some scheduled actions as you donot need 100% CPU Utilization during non-working hours.

The best possible option is to use **AWS AutoScaling with Scheduled actions**.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/schedule_time.html

AWS AutoScaling can launch new EC2 instances based on your CPU Utilization (or other metrics like Network Load, Disk read/write etc). This way you can always keep your site alive.

Using the AutoScaling scheduled actions you can specify metrics such that you stop your autoscaled instances during non-working hours and autoscale instances during working hours according to CPU Utilization(or other metrics).

You can even stop your severs if you donot need them at some point of time.

If you are not familiar with AWS AutoScaling you can follow the Documentation which is very precise and easy.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html

Comment: Agreed. A third option, of course, is to **investigate what processes are consuming CPU within your system**. Use standard methods (eg looking at processes, memory, disk access) to determine the bottlenecks in your system.

Comment: @john, how can i investigate/find which process sonsuming cpu.

Comment: @Ali, I will try your suggestion. later i will give response of your answer.
One more thing my website have one ajax call every 3 seconds so may be it cause for this CPU utilization issue ?

Comment: Ajax call every 3 seconds, sounds interesting. Also, Try John's suggestion and find the CPU utilization of each process ---> Linux cmd: { ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd }. If it is Windows u can figure out CPU utilization in Task Manager.

Comment: @Mech, investigating resource consumption is not specific to Amazon EC2. Use any tips you can find online for Linux. Start with `top` and drill-down from there.

Comment: @Ali, Below images are show CPU usage, httpd command consume more. Can you suggest fot it what settings need so httpd command take less cpu usage.
[link](**http://screencast.com/t/1jV98WqhCLvV**)
[link](**http://screencast.com/t/PbXF5EYI**)
When using many(5) user simultaneously use website then
[link](**http://screencast.com/t/QZgZsiNgdCUl**)

Answer (score 0):

If the cpu utilization reach 100% bacause of the **number of visitors** your site have, you must consider to change the instance type,  [Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html) or [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/en/cloudfront/dynamic-content/) in order to cache as many http requests as posible (static and dynamic content).

If visitors are not the problem and there are other scheduled tasks on the EC2 isntance, I strongly recomend to decouple these workload via [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/en/sqs/) & [AWS Elasticbeanstalk - Worker type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)